# Get valueForKeyPath from nsmutableArray Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a nsmutableArray "downloadProgress" which consists of a string and a floatvalue.
I need to find the float value from another class.
currently I am using

```
[[observedDownloads_ valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.downloadProgress"] floatValue];
```

but this wont give me the float value as it is inside the array downloadProgress.

How Do I access it.

Comment: What exactly does the array contain?

Comment: You need to use objectAtIndex: to access a particular piece of data inside an array.

Comment: contains a string at index 0 and float at index 1

Comment: It can't contain a `float`, `NSArray`s can only contain objects. Does it contain an `NSNumber`? Is the string numerical? If not, it won't have a valid `floatValue`.

Answer (score 0):

you doing wrong. you can get Value like bellow example:-

```
[[observedDownloads_ valueForKeyPath:@"avg.downloadProgress"]objectAtIndex:1];
```